# About Junit Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Source code:

```
public int Randoms(ModelAndView model) {
        int ra =0;
        if(model!=null){
            Random random = new Random();
            ra=random.nextInt(10) + 1;
            model.addObject("ra", ra);

        }
        return ra;
    }
```

Junit code:

```
    public void testRandoms() throws Exception {
        when(baseController.Randoms(any())).thenReturn(10);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = mock(ModelAndView.class);
        modelAndView.setViewName("test");
        int result = baseController.Randoms(modelAndView);
        Assert.assertTrue(result<10);
    }
```

error info:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at com.hp.billing.controller.BaseControllerTest.testRandoms(BaseControllerTest.java:29)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(any());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

Error Code :
when(baseController.Randoms(any())).thenReturn(10);

but I try edit:
when(baseController.Randoms(isA(ModelAndView.class))).thenReturn(10);

it's also error, I don't how to fix it.

It's Junit4 & mockito 5.0

First time contact with JUnit, how to modify the test code?

Comment: You want to test the controller but also mock it, then what use is the test?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the method you are trying to test is in the controller level `baseController`. You would only need to use Mock if your method was calling further methods (let's say if you had further logic in `baseService`)

So in your scenario I would just write a test, set a static expected response (eg int = 10) and assert that it matches the actual one when you call the method.